# Quiz and ContentEditable tag

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm making a short simple html quiz with the help of some javascript. The problem is I don't want to use `<input>` to accept the answers and I'm looking for an alternative. The javascript runs the input against the tags ID. Would it be possible to use another tag with contenteditable. I want the box to say "type answer here". If the javascript checks ID1, could I have something like,

```
<p id="id1" contenteditable="true">Type answer here</p>
```

Instead of

```
<input type="text" id="id1">
```

It seems ok in theory but when I test it it's like it's not running what I typed in against the javascript. Any suggestions?

Update: I'm guessing it's not working because perhaps contenteditable doesn't actually change the text in the tag. Any alternatives / workarounds to the  tag. Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `<input>`? It's brilliant for accepting user input.

Comment: Absolutely it is. However this is in reference to ibooks in IOS6. And <input> isn't working currently. We already had to use a workaround in IOS5 to add interactivity.

Comment: How is `<input>` not working correctly?

Comment: In the epub environment, loaded into IOS6, ibooks (which I referred to in the above post), <input type="text"> currently does not prompt the keyboard.

Comment: If you are already having problems with the keyboard in a plain <input>, then trying to use contentEditable to workaround them is absolutely crazy.

Comment: Don't be so close-minded. I'm not an apple developer, and I don't have any real say over how ibooks interprets HTML tags at any point. My job is to give my clients alternatives, and that's what I'm asking about, I'm not looking for opinions. "Absolutely crazy" - Not a good statement for any developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-form elements don't have a `value` property in JavaScript. You'll have to use either `innerHTML` or `textContent` (depending on whether you want to preserve HTML tags or not) to get the value.

↪ [View an example at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkANZ/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the typed text from a contenteditable element using its `value` property (like an input) then you're out of luck because it doesn't have one. You need `innerHTML` or `textContent` instead (depending on whether or not you want to ignore formatting).